# Checkbox loses HTML5 attributes on postback?

Tags: asp.net, .net, postback

Inside a Repeater control, I add custom HTML5 attributes to all checkboxes on `ItemDataBound` to identify the row it belongs to, as well as its parent checkbox (if any).  For example, the below checkbox html indicates the row ID for the Great Britain & Ireland checkbox, and it also indicates that the EMEA checkbox is the Great Britain & Ireland checkbox's parent.

[image]

```
<input id="ctl00_CP1_salesControl_rptTotalSales_ctl01_cbActivated" type="checkbox" 
  name="ctl00$CP1$salesControl$rptTotalSales$ctl01$cbActivated" checked="checked"
  data-row-id="ctl00_CP1_salesControl_rptTotalSales_ctl01_row" 
  data-control-id="activation-checkbox" 
  data-parent-checkbox-id="ctl00_CP1_salesControl_rptTotalSales_ctl00_cbActivated">
```

However, when I click a button which posts back to the server to validate the data, these custom attributes are lost, and I am left with the following:

```
<input id="ctl00_CP1_salesControl_rptTotalSales_ctl01_cbActivated" type="checkbox" 
 name="ctl00$CP1$salesControl$rptTotalSales$ctl01$cbActivated" checked="checked">
```

It's strange in that the dropdown lists and textboxes, which also contain custom attributes added on ItemDataBound, retain these attributes after postback.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the ItemDataBound event fire on postback? If not, then why would the attributes be there?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if enabling the viewstate for the checkboxes fixes this

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.  However, I was able to eliminate the issue by changing the control to a regular HTML checkbox like so `<input type="checkbox" runat="server" ID="cbActivated" checked='<%#Item.IsActivated%>'/>`